# Body onload event after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Each time after I make an ajax call, I am replacing the whole html with a new content with `$("html").html(ajaxresponse)`. But the onload event on my body element is not triggering after ajax completed.

```
 <body onload="{% if not test.is_finished %} doTimer() {% endif %}">
```

So I have a timer, what i want to keep counting until the test is finished. For example after an ajax call if the `test.is_finished` changed to `true` I dont want the `doTimer()` function to run anymore. It works fine if i am not using ajax.Do you have any suggestions how can i make it work?

Comment: because there is no loading after an ajax call

Comment: There's no reason at all to use the body load event for this, even if it did work.

Comment: And what would be the best other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onload` event only fires if the webpage is being loaded (or re-loaded). AJAX based requests don't trigger a page-(re-)load and therefor your `onload` listener doesn't fire when the request arrives. That's how it is supposed to work.

Instead of using `onload`, try to call your `doTimer()` callback when the AJAX response arrives. If you need to have it called when the page loads, call it in both places (`onload` & when AJAX requests arrive).

The following is an example that should give you an idea. Please note that it makes certain assumptions:

- Requests should be fired based on user interactions (for example: A button is clicked)
- Your endpoint returns JSON with two fields: `tests_finished` and `markup`
- You want to run `doTimer()` if and only if `tests_finished` has a value of `true`

**HTML:**

```
<button id="submit">Send AJAX</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

**JSON structure:**

```
{
  "tests_finished": Boolean,
  "markup": String
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var AJAX_URL = 'PATH/TO/RESOURCE';

var $output = $('#output');
var $button = $('#submit');

$button.on('click', runAjax);

function runAjax() {
  $.ajax(AJAX_URL, {
    // your settings
  })
  .done(processResponse)
  .fail(processFailures);
}

function processResponse(json) {
  $result.html(json.markup);
  if (json.tests_finished) {  
    doTimer(); // <-- called here instead of "onload"
  }
}

function processFailures(exc) {
  console.error(exc);
}

function doTimer() {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

body onload event will be executed only once or on window refresh.
I assume you are using setInterval, if not you can use setInterval and after ajax call is completed you can clear the interval.

Comment: I am not using setInterval. My timer is running on the server side, and each time when i make a request i send to the client the remaining seconds.